# How does $\cos x=\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have seen the following definition many times:
$$\cos x=\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$$ However, it makes little sense to me as it appears far from obvious. Please help me understand this definition, either a derivation or explanation of how the values on the right equal $\cos x$.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)?

Comment: @Dale, use the Taylor expansions of these functions.

Comment: The formula you have is a direct result of Euler's formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Euler's formula,

$e^{ix}=\cos x+i \sin x$

$e^{-ix}=\cos x-i\sin x$

then,

$e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2\cos x \Rightarrow \cos x=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$.

Comment: Euler observed that if you extend the real function $e^x$ to the complex plane by means of the power series, you have $e^ae^b=e^{a+b}$ for all complex $a,b.$ And the rest follows.

Answer (score 3):

Euler's formula states that
$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$
By replacing $x$ with $-x$ and using the parities of the trigonometric functions (the sine is odd and the cosine even) we get
$$e^{-ix}=\cos x-i\sin x$$
Adding these two equations together we get
$$e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2\cos x$$
and finally
$$\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2=\cos x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use $e^{ix}=\cos (x)+i\sin (x)$ and $-\sin (x)=\sin (-x) $

Answer (score 1):

$e^{ix}=\cos x+i \sin x$, so $e^{-ix}=\cos(-x)+i\sin(-x)=\cos x-i\sin x$. Adding these two equations you get the required formula.

Answer (score 1):

Taylor series of $\cos(x)$:
$$\begin{align}
\cos(x)&=\color{green}{1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x4}{4!}-\cdots}
\end{align}$$

---

Taylor series of $e^x$:
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$$
Taylor series of $e^{ix}$:
$$\begin{align}
e^{ix}&=1+ix+\frac{(ix)^2}{2!}+\frac{(ix)^3}{3!}+\frac{(ix)^4}{4!}\cdots\\
&=\color{green}{1}+ix\color{green}{-\frac{x^2}{2!}}-\frac{ix^3}{3!}\color{green}{+\frac{x^4}{4!}}\cdots
\end{align}$$

Taylor series of $e^{-ix}$:
$$\begin{align}
e^{-ix}&=1-ix+\frac{(-ix)^2}{2!}+\frac{(-ix)^3}{3!}+\frac{(-ix)^4}{4!}\cdots\\
&=\color{green}{1}-ix\color{green}{-\frac{x^2}{2!}}+\frac{ix^3}{3!}\color{green}{+\frac{x^4}{4!}}\cdots
\end{align}$$

So adding the above two together, the imaginary parts cancel out each other and the real parts are twice those in $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac 12 (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$.

Then it is easy to show that $y=f(x)$ is a solution to 
$$y''+y=0 \,;\, y(0)=1, y'(0)=0 $$

But this equation has unique solution, and $\cos(x)$ is also a solution to this.